# If telnet output contains something execute action

Tags: bash, telnet

I am trying to write a small script in bash. My target is that a Phone Call on my FritzBox will mute or pause my TV.

I get the information of a call via telnet (telnet fritz.box 1012) on my RaspberryPi and if there is coming a phone call in I get this output:

24.08.15 14:03:05;RING;0;017mobilephonenumber;49304myhomenumber;SIP0;

The only Part that is every time the same is the RING before the calling number. What I need is a script that checks the output of the telnet and if in the telnet output is a ring than execute an action in my case i just need to do a http request on an internal site or start another script.

This is what I have tried is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

#string='echo "My string"'
string=$(telnet –e p fritz.box 1012)
for reqsubstr in 'alt' 'RING';do
  if [ -z "${string##*$reqsubstr*}" ] ;then
      echo "String '$string' contain substring: '$reqsubstr'."
    else
      echo "String '$string' don't contain substring: '$reqsubstr'."
    fi
  done
```

But I don`t get the output of my telnet session into the string. Anyone who can help me?

Comment: try using your `telnet` from a command line. Usually, you have to type `quit` or `exit` (etc) to terminate a session. You may even have to use Ctrl-C (Don't have access to telnet right now). Good luck.

Comment: A simpler check in `bash` is `if [[ $string = *$reqsubstr* ]]`; then

Comment: Tag this with `expect` and I suspect @GlennJackman will know the answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my short conclusion:
To see incomming calls on your FritzBox you can simply execute:
    `telnet fritz.box 1012`
in your terminal.
The output should look like that:

```
24.08.15 14:03:05;RING;0;017mobilephonenumber;49304myhomenumber;SIP0;
```

I my case I want the execute an command the mutes my TV.
Here are the [instructions](http://www.domoticz.com/wiki/Harmony_Hub_Control) how I controll my TV via Web/RaspberryPi (Philips Harmony Hub) if some one is interested.

To execute a command on an incomming call create a script called action.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
while true;
do
  read logline
  for substr in 'alt' '\;RING\;'
  do
    if [[ "$logline" = *${substr}* ]]; then
      echo "Got a match"
      #here you can put the command you want to execute on an incoming call
    fi
  done
done
```

After you create it make it executable using `chmod +x action.sh`
After that you can start the script using `nc 192.168.1.1 1012 | action.sh`
And that's how you execute a script on an incomming call!
Special thanks to tgo!!

Answer (score 2):

After you latest comment, and reading your question again, I think we can go for something simpler based on `nc` (netcat).

Let assume we create a bash script called action.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
while true;
do
  read logline
  for substr in 'alt' '\;RING\;'
  do
    if [[ "$logline" = *${substr}* ]]; then
      echo "Got a match"
    fi
  done
done
```

Make the script executable, `chmod +x action.sh`, then start it with `nc` as follow:

```
nc -l fritz.box 1012 | ./action.sh
```

It will listen infinitely for incoming traffic from the box and should act as you want.  I don't have your box obviously and I tested by starting it as `nc -l 127.0.0.1 12000` and then provided input via `telnet 127.0.0.1 12000`, providing your RING sample. It seems to work.

```
$ nc -l 127.0.0.1 12000 | ./action.sh
Got a match
017mobilephonenumber
Got a match
017mobilephonenumber
```

Would this be more acceptable to you ? without expect (I am not an expect wizard anyway).

I hope this answer will help you more.

Comment: Thanks a lot that is exact what i was looking for… but if i execute the     nc -l fritz.box 1012 | ./action.sh command I get     nc: Address family not supported by protocol so i thought i put in there the ip address like this     nc -l 192.168.1.1 1012 | /home/pi/Desktop/action.sh but then I get    nc: Cannot assign requested address do you have an Idea?

Comment: it's because nc is trying to create a socket with a port < than 1024.  It was shown as an example for testing because I don't have access to a box or service like yours.

Comment: Perfect it works thank you very much! I will write a small short conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

do you have access to `expect`?  It is meant exactly for such kind of scenario. `man expect` is your friend, and I found [a fair tutorial](https://nigibox.wordpress.com/2010/01/18/automating-and-scripting-sshftptelnet-session-with-expect/) via google.  If you google for `modem expect` you can find sample script for such scenario (I can find some for FritzBox too but not sure it's the same box as yours). I haven't used it in ages, though.

Comment: How would this work? I saw some scripts but I understand them?

Comment: I took a nearer look at your link. I understand that you can "search" with "expect" in the telnet session. But I don't want to send something to the FritzBox. I just want to run another script if "expect" became true.

Comment: Indeed, I missed that.  Do I understand correctly that what you want is to monitor permanently the output of the `telnet` and whenever a line matches your pattern, execute a command on your raspberry pi ?  I will fiddle a bit with that if you confirm, I thought it was possible.

Comment: ah! Good, I am glad.  I hope it really works for you.